# Applying matrix product in specific pandas columns

Tags: python, matrix, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I have a pandas DataFrame structured in the following way

```
   0     1    2     3         4         5         6      7      8     9 
0  42  2012  106  1200  0.112986 -0.647709 -0.303534  31.73  14.80  1096
1  42  2012  106  1200  0.185159 -0.588728 -0.249392  31.74  14.80  1097
2  42  2012  106  1200  0.199910 -0.547780 -0.226356  31.74  14.80  1096
3  42  2012  106  1200  0.065741 -0.796107 -0.099782  31.70  14.81  1097
4  42  2012  106  1200  0.116718 -0.780699 -0.043169  31.66  14.78  1094
5  42  2012  106  1200  0.280035 -0.788511 -0.171763  31.66  14.79  1094
6  42  2012  106  1200  0.311319 -0.663151 -0.271162  31.78  14.79  1094
```

In which columns 4, 5 and 6 are actually the components of a vector. I want to apply a matrix multiplication in these columns, that is to replace columns 4, 5 and 6 with the vector resulting of a the multiplication of the previous vector with a matrix.

What I did was

```
    DC=[[ .. definition of multiplication matrix .. ]]
    def rotate(vector):
            return dot(DC, vector)
    data[[4,5,6]]=data[[4,5,6]].apply(rotate, axis='columns')
```

Which I thought should work, but the returned DataFrame is exactly the same as the original.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Go back a step and check if `rotate(data[col]) == data[col]` for col in 4, 5, 6

Comment: @JohnE I do not think you understand my question. I'll edit it to make it clearer. And `DC`is 3x3, because every row of data[[4,5,6]] is a 3d vector. So it should be applied to each row separately.

Comment: @JoeCondron Thank for the tip. The data I was using was actually coincidentally arranged in a way that the matrix `DC` was actually coming out as the identity matrix. Which is pretty weird for field data, but anyway I modified the data a little bit, tried again and it turns out my code was correct. Sorry for the trouble and thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually going to add 'if so then DC must be the identity matrix' :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct but very slow. You can use `values` property to get the ndarray and use `dot()` to transform all the vectors at once:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

DC = np.random.randn(3, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 10))
df2 = df.copy()
df[[4,5,6]] = np.dot(DC, df[[4,5,6]].values.T).T

def rotate(vector):
        return np.dot(DC, vector)
df2[[4,5,6]] = df2[[4,5,6]].apply(rotate, axis='columns')
df.equals(df2)
```

On my PC, it's about 90x faster.

Comment: So just to be clear, in your example you're doing the same thing with df (your way) and then re-doing it with df2 (my way), right? Because if so, then yes, I see why it's faster.